# get the next day and previous day of a selecteddate on flex!

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript

I was wondering if there is a function/method to get next and previous date of a selected day
something like getpreviousday hh or something?
all I could find is function that people created themselves, I thought maybe there is already a built-in function.

Answer (score 2):

Use this [ActionScript DateUtils](http://flexdateutils.riaforge.org/) library.

There is a DateAdd method you can use:

```
var currentDate : Date = new Date();
var nextDate : Date = DateUtils.dateAdd('date',1,currentDate);
var previousDate : Date = DateUtils.dateAdd('date',-1,currentDate);
```

Comment: where did you get DateUtils from? i cant find it

Comment: @gongo12 Click the link I pointed two and click the download project button; roughly in the middle of the screen.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the DateUtil from here: [DateUtils at code.google.com](http://code.google.com/p/flexdateutils/wiki/DateUtils)

Further [www.flextras.com](https://stackoverflow.com/users/133840/www-flextras-com) mentioned the link for ActionScript Dateutils.